# Refresh Page on a Specific Time in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to refresh a page on a specific time.

From `http-equiv="refresh" content="30"` the page is refresh very 30 seconds,But I want page is refreshed on the specific time. like page is refresh on 1:30 of every day.

Comment: What is your goal, please explain the scenario?

Comment: Yes, because without understanding the goal, this is a bit confusing.  You would be dependent on the browser being open, the local time of the machine, etc, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime targetDate = ...;
long secondsTilRefresh = Math.Floor((targetDate - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds);
```

Then, just use that value to fill the meta refresh tag.  Of course, their browser may not remain open that long, and/or the browser may not support large values.

Answer (score 3):

You could use javascript to create a countdown timer that starts when the page is loaded in the browser?

Add this to your page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout("window.location = 'yourpage.aspx'", <%= CalcMilisecsToNext130pm() %>);
</script>
```

You could probably hack something together inline to get the number of milliseconds until 1:30pm. Else just create simple method in your codebehind...

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page means sending a request to the server. You can write a Windows Service that sends a request to your page every day at 1:30.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use JavaScript on page load to calculate the time difference between now and when you want to next load the page. Then set a timeout (window.setInterval) to occur at that time. Then you can set the JavaScript "location" to the same page and presto - page loads at the scheduled time.

Jakob beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Server time put this:

```
<% DateTime dte = DateTime.Now; %>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=86400 - (((dte.Hour * 60) + dte.Minute) * 60) %>">
```

for client based time use the javascript setTimeout method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like, get hours difference between now and tommrow date and convert into millisecs then use settime out

```
var todayDateTime = new Date();
var tommorowDateTimeAtSixAM = new Date(todayDateTime.getFullYear(), todayDateTime.getMonth(), todayDateTime.getDate(), 6, 0, 0);

var hoursdifference = Math.abs(tommorowDateTimeAtSixAM .getTime()-todayDateTime.getTime())/3600000; 

var milliSecondsDifference = hoursdifference * 60 * 60 *1000;

setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
}, milliSecondsDifference);
```